# Defining multiple ranges with an if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a situation where I have a table called districts with a column called zone, for which 410 values, numbers 1-410 are stored...

Currently, the R code is structured like this:

```
# add II data to the external matrix
zoneNames <- districts$zone
maxExternalZoneNum <- 99 #assumes externals first in zone numbering and are less than 99
vehicle[zoneNames > maxExternalZoneNum, zoneNames > maxExternalZoneNum] <- get(paste(p, "vehicle", sep=""))[zoneNames > maxExternalZoneNum, zoneNames > maxExternalZoneNum]
assign(paste(p, "vehicle", sep=""),vehicle)
rm(vehicle)
```

Except that for my purpose, the 99 maxExternalZoneNum does not apply.  I have 1-30 external zone numbers plus another external zone number, 410.

31-409 are "internal" zones, and cannot be renumbered.  So I must define maxExternalZoneNum as a range of values, 1:30 and 410.

What methods could I deploy to efficiently handle the change in the maxExternalZoneNum so that it does not break the execution of this code?

Comment: In simple English, can you please tell us what you are doing?I didn't understand your code.

Comment: Metrics--it's part of a very large and complex travel demand model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
district$zone<-with(district,ifelse((zone<=30|zone==410),"external","internal")
```

Or you can use `%in%` as suggested by Frank:

```
district$zone<-with(district,ifelse((zone %in% c(1:30,410)),"external","internal")
```

Comment: `(zone<=30|zone==410)` could be replaced with `(zone %in% c(1:30, 410))`, which probably generalizes better to other situations

Comment: I would include both options to be most useful for future reference.  The %in% operator doesn't work as well for non-integer sets of numbers.

Comment: This will probably work, but for clarification, what is "external" and "internal" supposed to represent?  Internal zones = 31-409, so would I define a new object internal <- 31:40 and external would be??? 1:30, 410?

Comment: This will replace your existing zone variable with two categories: external (if zone takes a value 1 to 30 and 410) or internal (if it takes a value 31 to 409). If you want to create new variable rather than replacing existing zone variable, you can just do district$new on left hand side of the code.